# How to use Dynamic Data provider and EntityDataSource control for Entity Framework 6?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to know how to use Dynamic Data provider for Entity Framework 6  released in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/28/announcing-the-release-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx)

Is there a lesson or a tutorial on how to use it ?